# how to centering Title Without being affected by headerLeft in react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I use react navigation and I'm centering the title in the bar but it's affected with headerLeft, 
when I turn off them it's work and center the title exactly,
how to do this without affecting the title with another left and right button\icon

[image: is not centering]

[image: centering when delete the logout button]

code:

```
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
   screen: Home,
   navigationOptions: {
     title: "Home",
    //headerLeft: null, // here the issue
     headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(42,55,68)',
     },
      headerTitleStyle: {
         flex: 1,
         textAlign: 'center',
         color: "#fff",
       }
    }
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

No issue with your `headerTitleStyle` props, just make sure to have a View for both headerLeft and headerRight.

Example:

```
 headerLeft : (<View><Entypo name='menu' size={28} color='white' onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} /></View>),
 headerRight:(<View></View>)
```

Comment: oh, I didn't have imported React in Router file :] but now it takes more time to navigate, have any idea?